# Cassandra: Cassandra node is taking 20-25 min on restart

Tags: cassandra

Have restarted one of the node in the cluster and it took 20-25 min to start the service(before restart have executed nodetool flush).
the data folder size is around 1.1 TB on the machine.

cluster data : we are having 2 datacenter, and each DC is have 7 nodes with replication factor 2.

Below are the debug logs and i see there is 25 min gap between two loggers.

```
DEBUG [CompactionExecutor:3] **2023-07-04 07:00:30,058** CompactionTask.java:255 - Compacted 

INFO  [main] **2023-07-04 07:25:41,491** IndexSummaryManager.java:85
```

based on debug logs i understood that, all the table compactions are done and it initialized indexsummary manager.

want to know which process took  25 minutes b/w compaction and index summary initialisation.

Answer (score 0):

> it took 20-25 min to start the service

I've seen this happen before in very write-heavy clusters where the commit logs were not being processed fast enough.  Thus, there was a large amount of data in the commit log that had to be reconciled at restart-time.

> (before restart have executed nodetool flush).

So I would think that should have done it.  Flush, by definition, initiates that reconciliation between the memtables, the commitlog, and the sstables.

Perhaps, it might be a better idea to run a `nodetool drain` instead (prior to restart).  Drain does some extra things around making sure that everything is taken care of prior to shutdown.

To get this under control, I would add more nodes to the cluster.  Making each node responsible for less data and spreading out the operational write load will help the root cause of this issue.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, will try drain on restart.